# Number of Different Chains with Length N

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There 2 types of balls Red, and Blue.
Any Red ball can be marked by the letters A, B or C.
Any Blue ball can be marked by the letters D, E, F.

Let's mark by $ {a}_{n} $ the number of different chains which can be created by $ n $ balls with the restriction of no more than 2 balls with the same color in a row.

Namely, { Blue (D), Blue (F), Blue (E) } isn't valid, while { Red (A), Red (C), Blue (F) } is valid.

How can one define $ {a}_{n} $ in recursive form?

I know the answer is (Or at least one of them, I'd be happy to more than one) is:

$$ {a}_{n} = 54 {a}_{n - 3} + 3 {a}_{n - 1} $$

Yet I don't understand why.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corrected version.**

Suppose that $\sigma$ is a valid chain of $n$ balls. One way to build such a chain is to start with a valid chain $\tau$ of length $n-1$ and add a ball whose color is different from that of the last ball in $\tau$. That is, if $\tau$ ends with a blue ball, we add a red ball, and *vice versa*. There are three types of red ball and three types of blue ball, so either way we have $3$ ways to extend $\tau$ to $\sigma$; that gives us $3a_{n-1}$ valid chains of length $n$. Specifically, it gives us all of the valid chains of length $n$ whose last two balls are not the same color.

Now we have to count the valid chains $\sigma$ of length $n$ whose last two balls **are** the same color. Let $\tau$ be the chain consisting of the first $n-2$ balls of $\sigma$; $\tau$ must be valid, and there are two possibilities: either the last two balls of $\sigma$ are red and the last ball of $\tau$ is blue, or *vice versa*. Moreover, if $\rho$ is any valid chain of length $n-2$, we can add two balls of the color that is not that of the last ball of $\rho$ to get a valid chain of length $n$ ending in two balls of the same color. There are $3^2=9$ **red-red** chains and $3^2=9$ **blue-blue** chains, so no matter which valid chain of length $n-2$ we start with, there are $9$ ways to extend it to a valid chain of length $n$ whose last two balls are the same color. Thus, there are $9a_{n-2}$ such chains of length $n$ if $n\ge 3$. (This doesn’t apply when $n=2$, because then $\tau$ is the empty chain, and we can add either **red-red** or **blue-blue**.

Putting the pieces together, we see that $a_n=3a_{n-1}+9a_{n-2}$ for $n\ge 3$.

**Added:** Let’s do a little numerical checking. Clearly $a_0=1$: the empty chain is valid. There are $6$ chains of length $1$, all of which are valid, so $a_1=6$. There are $6^2=36$ chains of length $2$, and all are valid, so $a_2=36$. There are $6^3=216$ chains of length $3$, but now some are invalid. Specifically, the $3^3=27$ **red-red-red** chains and the $3^3=27$ **blue-blue-blue** chains are invalid. That leaves $216-54=162$ valid chains of length $3$, and sure enough, $3\cdot36+9\cdot6=108+54=162$.

Comment: @Ross: You’re right.

Comment: it seems to be correct up to 4 (I will chck it for 5 with MATLAB later). I understand your solution. Could you suggest how to get to the solution I wrote above?

Comment: @Drazick: You mean $a_n= 54a_{n-3}+3a_{n-1}$? That’s simply not correct. If it were, we’d have $a_n= 54a_{n-3}+3a_{n-1}=3a_{n-1}+9a_{n-2}$ and hence $54a_{n-3}=9a_{n-2}$, i.e., $6a_{n-3}=a_{n-2}$. But then we’d have $a_n=6a_{n-1}$, which is not true for $n=3$, for instance.